# How to autorelease a non returned object under ARC

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, foundation

Consider a function like this one:

```
void* getData()
{
    void* data= malloc(32);
    NSData* __autoreleasing dataObject= [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy: data length: 32 freeWhenDone: YES]
    return data;
}
```

If I try to execute this code and print the values (though they're not initialised, but just to make a test) in the area of memory returned, I don't get any exception.

But if I try to put a breakpoint and see the map of living objects, there isn't a NSData object alive, though data is still in the heap, why?

I would know how to return an autoreleased object, like before ARC. ARC handles everything, but in this case data is deallocated because I exit from the function scope. How to make it be alive and autoreleased after the call?

Comment: I don't think any trickery is needed here. Not even `__autoreleasing`. ARC [knows that if you're returning an allocated object, that needs to be autoreleased](http://www.galloway.me.uk/2012/02/how-does-objc_retainautoreleasedreturnvalue-work/).

Comment: @H2CO3: `getData` returns a pointer to a buffer, not an object.

Comment: @NateChandler But that's wrong anyway, it should return at least an `id`, better `NSData *` - it returns the data object, not its buffer.

Comment: But I need to return a raw pointer. I could use a static (primitive) array, but that's still not what I want.

Comment: I think the intent is to get ARC to manage the buffer so that when the autorelease pool is drained, the buffer is freed.  (This is made ambiguous by the fact that both the pointer to the buffer and the `NSData` object are named `data`.)  I tend to agree that it's "wrong", but I think it's an interesting concept, at least academically.

Comment: I modified the names to make it more understandable.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri So you want to return the raw pointer? Well, ARC won't manage that for you. ARC only manages objects.

Comment: That's why I wrap it into the data object.

Comment: @H2CO3 When an `NSData` object which is initialized via `dataWithBytesNoCopy:length:freeWhenDone:` is deallocated, the associated buffer is freed.  (From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSData/dataWithBytesNoCopy:length:freeWhenDone:), "The returned object takes ownership of the bytes pointer and frees it on deallocation.")  Consequently, if the `NSData` object were put into the autorelease pool, the buffer would be freed when the autorelease pool was drained.

Comment: @NateChandler I see. Now I suspect this is not quite possible.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri The question, then, seems to reduce to "Can an object be manually autoreleased under ARC."  If it can, your scheme can work out.  If it can't, you can put your function in another source file which is compiled using `-fno-objc-arc`.

Comment: Without ARC this was totally possible, the data object was caught by the autorelease pool and deallocated when out of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible. ARC was designed to automatically deallocate objects which are not accessible. Since the NSData object is local and not returned, it cannot be used, so ARC deallocates it.

Judging from the code you posted, it appears that you want to return a pointer to some data which will be automatically freed even though it is not an objective-c object. You may also want to be able to access this data using NSData APIs inside the function which generates it. You have a few options here.

1. Change your code to return the NSData object. If the calling code wants direct access to the buffer it can using the NSData's `bytes` method. However, this will not work if your code is called from C.
2. Stop trying to autorelease C data. Good C code should know when it needs to free data, so this should not be a problem. Simply change your code to `freeWhenDone: NO` and have the calling code use `free()` when it is done with the data.
3. Place this function in its own file and disable ARC for that file. This allows you to do what you want by manually calling `autorelease`, but you will also have to manually handle the reference counting for the rest of the function.
4. Combine 1 and 3. Have one function which uses ARC and returns the NSData object, and a wrapper function without ARC which calls the first to get an autoreleased object, then returns the buffer pointer from the result.

Comment: Now I've changed the NSData object to dataObject, hope it's more clear.

Comment: I removed that comment. The rest of my answer still applies, though, since I guessed right from the return type.

Comment: NSString's UTF8String method says: "The returned C string is automatically freed just as a returned object would be released; you should copy the C string if it needs to store it outside of the autorelease context in which the C string is created." That's the option 3 right?

Comment: Most likely, yes. The system frameworks probably do lots of things which aren't allowed/possible in ARC since they often have to be the interface between C and Objective-C.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to add a second function

```
NSData *autoreleaseBufferOfLength(void *bytes, NSUInteger length) 
{ 
    return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:bytes length:length freeWhenDone:YES]; 
}
```

This function will return an autoreleased `NSData` object.

Call this function from your buffer-returning function

```
void *getAutoreleasedBuffer(NSUInteger length)
{
    void *buffer = malloc(length);
    if (buffer) {
        autoreleaseBufferOfLength(buffer, length);
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

The `NSData` object returned from `autoreleaseBufferOfLength` is in the autorelease pool, so the buffer will be freed when the autorelease pool is drained (since the `NSData` object created in `autoreleaseBufferOfLength` is deallocated then).

I tested **for debug** this using this `main` function

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        __unused void * buffer = autoreleasingBuffer(32);

        NSLog(@"%s:exiting @autoreleasepool block", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    }
    NSLog(@"%s:exited @autoreleasepool block", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    return 0;
}
```

and by adding a symbolic breakpoint at `-[NSConcreteData dealloc]` with the action `po @"deallocating NSConcreteData"` and checking "Automatically continue after evaluating".  This was the output

```
[53030:303] int main(int, const char **):exiting @autoreleasepool block
(NSString *) $0 = 0x0000000100300530 deallocating NSConcreteData
[53030:303] int main(int, const char **):exited @autoreleasepool block
```

I then tested **for release**, changing the test slightly, adding a `__weak` global variable `g_data` which is set in `autoreleaseBufferOfLength`,

```
__weak NSData *g_data = nil;
NSData *autoreleaseBufferOfLength(void *bytes, NSUInteger length) 
{ 
    return (g_data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:bytes length:length freeWhenDone:YES]); 
}
```

and altering the logging in main:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool 
    {
        __unused void * buffer = autoreleasingBuffer(32);

        NSLog(@"%s:exiting @autoreleasepool block; g_data = %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, g_data);
    }
    NSLog(@"%s:exited @autoreleasepool block; g_data = %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, g_data);
    return 0;
}
```

When building for release and running this was the output:

```
[53934:707] int main(int, const char **):exiting @autoreleasepool block; g_data = 00000000 00000070 00000000 00000070 10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000>
[53934:707] int main(int, const char **):exited @autoreleasepool block; g_data = (null)
```

These tests indicate that wrapping the call to `dataWithBytesNoCopy:length:freeWhenDone:` in a second function `autoreleaseBufferOfLength` has the effect of creating an NSData object and placing it in the autorelease pool.

**Note**: This is *NOT* a good idea.  The best way to achieve a `malloc`'d which is `free`'d by the draining of the autorelease pool is to add a file which is built without ARC (using `-fno-objc-arc`), as @ughoavgfhw describes in his answer.  Nevertheless, this approach may be of some interest.

Comment: Yes, that have been useful too, +1.